# Workflow Rule / Similar based on number of records created

Tags: workflow, remedyforce

As an admin team we wish to be notified of any new mail loops in Remedyforce. I was thinking it would be good to create a notification email if we receive a new ticket from the same customer over 10 times in one hour?

Can anyone think of a workflow rule or similar that will send an email if x number of records have been created in an object over x amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with workflow or any other config-only option. You will need an APEX trigger to do a query for the tickets created in last hour each time a new ticket is created.